# Heritrix 3.2.0: Writing and Adding Extensions

Tags: spring, jar, web-crawler, heritrix

I am currently working with Heritrix and I have a standard installation (this one: http://builds.archive.org/maven2/org/archive/heritrix/heritrix/3.2.0/) and it works fine.

But now I want to write and add my own extensions e.g. change the priority of urls which should be crawled or just a simple extractor. I can inspect the java code of an existing extractor but how can I add it to the crawler?

I tried to export my java test project to a jar file and put this file in the lib folder of Heritrix (where the other libraries are). Furthermore I added a bean to my job's cxml file.

But after starting I got this error: 2014-11-07T19:51:40.296Z SEVERE Could not instantiate bean class [myModule.TestClass]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: myModule.TestClass.(); Can't create bean 'myModule.TestClass#0'

It is just the extractorHTML renamed and in a new project and exported to a jar file.

Any idea what is wrong? I read all the documentations but there are only explanations how to write extensions and not how to add it?

Greetings and thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the class loader requires a default constructor (A constructor - which takes no arguments)  Add a default constructor

```
public YourClass() { }
```

and the required getters and setters for setting the member variables.